# Spring MVC - HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've read all the questions related with this problem but no solution worked for me...

I have a simple upload form.
The controller, i't a controller i've used a lot of times (never for a file upload though).

```
@Controller
public class FileUploadController {
    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @RequestMapping(value={"/upload"}, method=  RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getUploadForm() {

        return "/upload";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value={"/upload"}, method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String uploadedFile(@RequestParam("uploadedFile") UploadedFile uploadedFile, BindingResult result, ModelMap model,
                                RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "/upload";

        } 
            InputStream is = null;
            OutputStream os = null;
            MultipartFile file = uploadedFile.getFile();
            String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
            String imagepath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/resources/images");
            try {
                is = file.getInputStream();
                File newFile = new File(imagepath+"/"+fileName);

                if(!newFile.exists()){
                    newFile.createNewFile();
                }
                os = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
                int read=0;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                while((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1){
                    os.write(bytes, 0, read);
                }
                redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("css", "success");
                redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("msg", "File "+fileName+ "aggiunto correttamente");
                model.addAttribute("fileName", fileName);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return "redirect:/floors";

    }

}
```

Then I have the upload form, cleaned form all the css part:

```
<form:form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" modelAttribute="uploadedFile">

         <input type="hidden"
             name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
             value="${_csrf.token}" />
        <form:errors path="*" cssClass="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible"
            element="div" />


            <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Carica
                immagine</label>

                <input type="file" name="file">
                <form:errors path="file" class="control-label" />


        <button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton"
                        class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Carica</button>

        </div>
    </form:form>
```

I don't know if it's useful, but this is UploadedFile.java, really simple

import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

```
public class UploadedFile{

    MultipartFile file;


    public MultipartFile getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(MultipartFile file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

}
```

The form in HTML has:

```
<form id="uploadedFile" class="form-horizontal" action="/smartpark/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Where is the problem? I cannot even understand at which point che POST request goes wrong...

I'm adding the debug: Spring debug says:

```
2015-12-22 18:52:13 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /upload at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2015-12-22 18:52:13 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /upload at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2015-12-22 18:52:13 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:192 - Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@468e6d7e: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationToken@468e6d7e: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@62dd304: Username: mario; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@7798: RemoteIpAddress: 192.168.3.38; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN'
2015-12-22 18:52:13 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /upload at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2015-12-22 18:52:13 DEBUG HstsHeaderWriter:128 - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@26ee04e5
2015-12-22 18:52:13 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /upload at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2015-12-22 18:52:13 DEBUG CsrfFilter:106 - Invalid CSRF token found for http://192.168.3.240:8080/smartpark/upload
2015-12-22 18:52:13 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:861 - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing POST request for [/smartpark/Access_Denied]
2015-12-22 18:52:13 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:306 - Looking up handler method for path /Access_Denied
2015-12-22 18:52:13 DEBUG ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver:133 - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
2015-12-22 18:52:13 DEBUG ResponseStatusExceptionResolver:133 - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
2015-12-22 18:52:13 DEBUG DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver:133 - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
2015-12-22 18:52:13 WARN  PageNotFound:208 - Request method 'POST' not supported
2015-12-22 18:52:13 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1034 - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2015-12-22 18:52:13 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1000 - Successfully completed request
2015-12-22 18:52:13 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper:211 - Skip invoking on
2015-12-22 18:52:13 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:105 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Browser network logs don't say anything, just that the POST resource is not accomplished

Thanks

Comment: On a side note. You can use the requestmapping annotation over your class `@Controller @RequestMapping("floors") public class`... That way you don't have to have a redundant constant over every method

Comment: Turn on your debug logs, check what Spring is registering as handler methods. Turn on your browser's network logs and check what is sent in your request. Post all of that.

Comment: Something in your security stack is forwarding the request to `/smartpark/Access_Denied`.

Comment: mmmm... maybe it's because of `DEBUG CsrfFilter:106 - Invalid CSRF token found `even if I pass it with the form...

Comment: I would recommend re-coding it from scratch using the guide:  https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/  .  Might be faster than trying to figure out where you went wrong.  Start with something super simple , then expand on it without breaking it.

Answer (score 1):

**Things to Consider:**

Check your request header and see if it's submitting to `floors/upload`. if not try to add action="floors/upload" property in your form tag.

Try to change your controller to (without the `path`)

```
 @RequestMapping(value="upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
```

Comment: I used the advice from @shinjw, but i got the same error, the HTML of the form goes to `<form id="uploadedFile" class="form-horizontal" action="/smartpark/floors/upload/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">`so it looks it goes to the right position...

Comment: Yes i did, I updated the question to reflect his advice

Comment: I already did it, thanks. I put everything at root level, now the mapping it's pointing to /upload directly

Comment: What is the line if (result.hasErrors()) ? maybe this causes the method to skip the uploading stuff

Comment: You mean that was the issue?

Comment: look my answer, the issue was about using spring security with multipart file upload

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.
Following this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-multipart) I saw that multipart file upload with spring and CSRF must be handled with care.

So I first disabled the CSRF to see if everything went well. After it, I added

`@Override
    protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
        insertFilters(servletContext, new MultipartFilter());
    }`

to my SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java so to not need the authentication to upload file on the server, but only to move them to their final destination.

Than I had to configure the filterMultipartResolver and everything went good.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Look into spring's PathVariables.

```
@RequestMapping(value = " /upload/{pathName}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String getOrder(@PathVariable String pathName){
 // do what you need
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ suggested I use `<form:form`, which uses gave

```
<html xmlns:form="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

at the top of my .html file. I changed to just `<form` in my body and then my POST request worked.